# Show that sequences in metric space converge to the same limit

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I need something to start out. I want to know the reasoning in solving problem related to metric space.

Let $f$ be a mapping of $(E,d)$ onto $(F,p)$ and $a$ is point in E.
$$\\$$
Show that if two sequences of elements of $E$ $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(a'_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to $a$,and provided that the two sequences $(f(a_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(f(a'_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge, then both should have the same limit.

This is what I've done : $$\\$$
Suppose that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(a_n) $= $l$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(a_n) $= $l'$. After this supposition , I don't find out how to continue it,

Comment: This is not true in general. In particular when $f$ is not supposed to be continuous which is not an hypothesis of your question.

Comment: You have already posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4006808/446262).

Comment: Well, if we suppose it's continuous then how can we do it?

Comment: Try at least to write a correct statement in your question.